# Will installing new Windows build remove any rootkits and trojans?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware, rootkit

I have currently installed 2004 version of Windows 10, if i update it to 20H2 version, will i get rid of any trojans or rootkits on my computer? Where are those typically get installed? I don't want to do format on my disk.

Answer (score 2):

Updating Windows does not affect any personal files, only system files. As any malicious software would not be a 'system file', there's a reasonable likelihood it would remain untouched.

See [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) for further information.